# Getting Search Data from Table - Elusive

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

What seems to be a simple problem became a complete nightmare.
I want to extract the gitscore from a person using BeautifulSoup.
The data is in a table with a tr-td structure where the desired data is in the td tags.

The desired format is:

```
[3499th of 9999, 90, 20, 70, 0]
```

This is the html:

```
<div id="results-pane" class="pane">
<h2 id="results-position">3499th of 9999</h2>
<div id="results-score">90</div>
<div id="results-close">×</div>
<table id="results-details">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Reputation</th>
    <th>Contribution</th>
    <th>Gist</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="social-score" class="detail-score">20</td>
    <td id="repo-score" class="detail-score">70</td>
    <td id="gist-score" class="detail-score">0</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I have tried several ways of resolving this.
The last is:

```
scores = sopa.find("table", {"id": "results-details"})
for s in scores.find_all("td"):
    print s
```

The output is:

```
<td class="detail-score" id="social-score"></td>
<td class="detail-score" id="repo-score"></td>
<td class="detail-score" id="gist-score"></td>
>>>
```

Which if I understand correctly indicates that there is no data.

In addition, when I add ".text" to the for loop I get the following error message:
    AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'

Just in case you want to check the site is: http://www.gitscore.com/user/name

How should I resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `BeautifulSoup` here. Make a `GET` request to the http://www.gitscore.com/user/name/calculate endpoint and parse the resulting JSON:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'With:XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36'
}
response = requests.get('http://www.gitscore.com/user/name/calculate', headers=headers)

result = response.json()
scores = result['scores']
print([
    '%s of %s' % (result['position'], result['totalScores']),
    scores['total'],
    scores['repo'],
    scores['user'],
    scores['gist'],
])
```

Here is what it prints for `octocat`:

```
['2 of 9999', 128351, 127316, 914, 121]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! The solution is great. Would I be able to make several continuous requests without any problems?

Comment: @Diego should not be a problem I think, but try maintaining the same web-scraping session using `request.Session()`. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to implement the "calculate" resource on a different site (ie: twitter) and did not work. Is there method to systematically get this type of json? Thanks!

Comment: @Diego nope, it's just that `gitscore` site has this endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
scores = sopa.find("table", {"id": "results-details"})
for s in scores.find_all("td"):
    print s.string
```

Comment: Thank you @DavidKHess, the result I am getting is "None, None, None", which is in line with the kind of difficulties I have been facing (no apparent data).